# In Flask, is there a way to have multiple checkboxes invoke different functions on an HTML input tag?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML file with an input tag and two checkboxes. In a Python file I have two functions meant to act on the input tag depending on which checkbox is selected. For some reason, the function meant to calculate the gc content does not work; only the first function seems to work. How do I fix this?

**HTML Code**

```html
    <form action="" method='POST' >
        <input name="sequence" type="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id= "count_nuc" name="check" value="check">
        <label for="count_nuc">Count nucleotides</label>
    
        <input type="checkbox" id= "gc_content" name="check" value="check">
        <label for="gc_content">GC content</label><br>
    
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
            
    {% if gc_percent %}
    <p>GC Percent: {{gc_percent}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if new_dict %}
    <p>Count nucleotides: {{new_dict}}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

**Python Code**

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    @app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def count_nucleotides():
        new_dict = {}
        nucleotides = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']
        seq = request.form.get('sequence')
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'sequence' in request.form and request.form.get("check"):
            for i in seq:
                if i not in nucleotides:
                    return 'Invalid nucleotide(s) found'
                else:
                    for j in nucleotides:
                        if j == i:
                            new_dict[i] = seq.count(i)
        return render_template('calculator.html', new_dict=new_dict)
    
    
    def gc_content():
        gc_percent = 0
        seq = request.form.get('sequence')
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'sequence' in request.form and request.form.get("check"):
            gc_percent += (round(((seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) * 100 / len(seq)), 2))
        return render_template('calculator.html', gc_percent=gc_percent)
    
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I don't see where you're actually calling the `gc_content()` function.

Comment: You mean adding "onclick = gc_content()" to one of the input tags?

Comment: onclick will call a JavaScript function, not a python function. You may need to re-think your design and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the whole idea needs to be-revised.

First, You need to have **two page**, one for displaying **the form**, and the other one for showing **the result**.

so you need to create two template:

**Form template** (form.html)

```
    <form action="/submit" method='POST' >
        <input name="sequence" type="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="count_nuc" name="count_check" checked>
        <label for="count_nuc">Count nucleotides</label>
    
        <input type="checkbox" id="gc_content" name="gc_check" checked>
        <label for="gc_content">GC content</label><br>
    
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**Result Template** (calculator.html)

```
    <h1>Result</h1>

    {% if gc_percent %}
    <p>GC Percent: {{gc_percent}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if new_dict %}
    <p>Count nucleotides: {{new_dict}}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

As you can see in the above code, I have also modified your HTML template, there were some mistakes for the name of checkbox elements that should be different from eachother.

**Python Code**

```py
  from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    @app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
    def form():
     
        return render_template('form.html')
    
    @app.route("/submit", methods=['POST'])
    def calculator():
        new_dict = {}
        nucleotides = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']
        seq = request.form.get('sequence')
        
        # Getting Value of Count Check Box
        if request.form.get("count_check"):
            count_check = True
            if count_check is True:
                for i in seq:
                    if i not in nucleotides:
                        return 'Invalid nucleotide(s) found'
                    else:
                        for j in nucleotides:
                            if j == i:
                                new_dict[i] = seq.count(i)
                            
                            
        gc_percent = 0
        # Getting Value of GC Check Box

        check = False
        if request.form.get("gc_check"):
            gc_check = True
            if gc_check is True:    
                gc_percent += (round(((seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) * 100 / len(seq)), 2))
            
        return render_template('calculator.html', gc_percent=gc_percent, new_dict=new_dict)
    
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The only thing that you need to check the code, because I'm not aware of your logic, and I've just tried to understand what was in your mind. If there was any ambiguous point, write a comment under this answer.

Comment: Thank you, with this I was able to add ~10 more functional checkboxes. Appreciate the help!